# Enter indents previous line?

Tags: emacs, yaml

In Emacs 24.3 (9.0) I'm using the latest `yaml-mode` installed via `el-get-update`. When I hit  `ENTER` at the end of a line, it has the unfortunate habit of auto-indenting the line I'm on before inserting the newline.

E.g. starting with this buffer:

```
foo:
  bar:
    - baz

baz:# <- Cursor here
```

Hitting enter results in the following buffer:

```
foo:
  bar:
    - baz

    baz: # <- unwanted indentation!
      # <- Cursor here
```

I've been working in a lot of YAML files lately, and this is slowly driving me mad. How do I stop it?

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, I'm not seeing this behavior in any other mode, just yaml-mode. I'm presently on commit `6d40a1dbd4c83f91d70f0e646e7bd8a45acc6fbf` from http://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode.

Comment: Does `C-j` do what you want (expect)? If so, just swap its key binding with that for `RET`.

Comment: I believe this is a recognized issue in the yaml-mode project: https://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode/issues/24 Hopefully someone can solve it soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments, something has caused `reindent-then-newline-and-indent` to get bound to `RET`.

I'm not sure where that binding came from, but you should be able to rebind `RET` to `newline-and-indent` in YAML mode like this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
        (define-key yaml-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)))
```

or simply to `newline` if you don't want automatic indenting of the next line:

```lisp
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
        (define-key yaml-mode-map "\C-m" 'indent)))
```

Comment: Adding that hook, when I next invoke `yaml-mode`, I get this error: `Symbol's function definition is void: electric-indent-local-mode`. Perhaps my emacs isn't as advanced as you think? I'm getting my OS X build from http://emacsformacosx.com/ if that's helpful.

Comment: @DavidEyk, that's possible. What's the full output of `M-x version`?

Comment: And just to clarify, I don't get this behavior in any other mode, just yaml-mode.

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.19)

Comment: @DavidEyk, I'm definitely wrong about how new your Emacs is. If you do `C-h k RET` from a YAML buffer, which command does it say it's running?

Comment: `(reindent-then-newline-and-indent)`. *That* doesn't sound like what I want. :)

Comment: @DavidEyk, it does not :-). If you do `(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook '(lambda () (define-key yaml-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)))` as suggested [in the README](https://github.com/yoshiki/yaml-mode/blob/master/README), do you get the desired behaviour? You could also use `newline` if you don't want auto-indenting of the new line.

Comment: The fix for my problem was in the README. How embarrassing! If you want to edit your answer, I'll happily accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEyk, not really. It's pretty unusual for `reindent-then-newline-and-indent` to be bound to the enter key, so this was a weird situation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I had to add `(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))` to the YAML mode hook.